# Zeppelin: how to read a DataFrame with sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-zeppelin

I have to use python with Zeppelin. I'm very new and I find only materials about pyspark into Zeppelin.
I want to import a dataframe with python and then access it through sql:

```
%python    
import pandas as pd #To work with dataset
import numpy as np #Math library     
#Importing the data
df_credit = pd.read_csv("../data.csv",index_col=0)
```

if I try with:

```
%python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
df_credit.to_sql('mydatasql',con=engine)
```

and then access it, i.e. :

```
%sql select Age, count(1) from mydatasql where Age < 30 group by Age order by Age
```

I get the error: "Table or view not found"

I think the problem is that %sql cannot read variables created with %python, but I'm not sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%python.sql` interpreter.
You have to install `pandasql` package.
Check this [link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/python.html#sql-over-pandas-dataframes) for more info.